# What is the risk of displaying specific error messages in credit card payment form?

Tags: validation, credit-card

I want to know whether it's okay to display specific error message something like "invalid cvv, insufficient credit etc.". Why and why not?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you're ok to display messages like that.. But there are caveats.

Some type of messages, such as 'CVC invalid', you can be fairly confident about. But I doubt you could ever confidently say 'insufficient credit', mainly because the card acquirers don't send that level of detail back. The best you'll get is a 'declined', but that could mean insufficient credit, or it could mean card blocked (marked as lost/stolen), or it could mean the bank don't trust the transaction (eg cardholder attempting purchase in another country, and haven't informed their bank they're travelling), or it could mean a dozen other things.

So I'd keep it simple and just repeat back the message that the card acquirer returns. Most often for failed transactions this is just simply DECLINED.